# Using a Third-Party API to dynamically create pages

Tags: services

I have a Drupal website that I'm working on where for section of it, I want to pull data in from an external API and dynamically create pages with this data. Do I need to create a custom module for this? I'm not too sure where to start with this, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, though without knowing the API your using, it's hard to nail down exactly what one you would need.

If it's a commonly used service, there might already be a module that exists for it. As a general rule, if there is a module already created to handle it, that should be the way to go.

You might be able to go slightly out of the box if your API spits out some form of feed and use a module to import that feed (it's a bit older, but as an example, [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) does this.) There's a few other ingestion modules out there that might work for you.

Creating your own custom module is, of course, always an option. I know I've written a few import modules, but I normally only do that when the other options are not viable.